# can I perform async calls in an EditContext.OnFieldChanged

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, eventhandler

Inside an [EditContext OnFieldChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.forms.editcontext.onfieldchanged?view=aspnetcore-7.0) event, when I have one specific field change, I need to write the change to the database. This is a Blazor server app and I use Entity Framework.

Is it ok for this to be async? Both will it work ok (it seems to). And equally important, will the user see no delay or pause?

This works fine in my testing. But that doesn't mean it will work great with any browser under any load in every situation. So are there concerns around this?

Comment: `OnFieldChanged` is an event.  It's *fire and forget*, so yes it's OK.  Just remember that the `EditContext` isn't awaiting your code.  Nor is the UI, so the user can click other buttons and change the data again while the Task runs. They will probably have to be very quick, but that behaviour is possible.  My gut sense is to lock the field [or maybe the form] while the save is going on, but without context I'm guessing.  You can implement this in the event hsndler.

Comment: Events are only fire-and-forget when you make them `async void`. Normally they are fully synchronous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OnFieldChanged  is an old style event, and its parameters have no writable properties.

So this is exactly what `async void` was intended for. When you want to update the UI (probably not) then add a StateHasChanged() at the end.

Using `async void` here is the lesser evil compared to not awaiting anything you do inside the method.

And it certainly beats doing any synchronous I/O because that would cause a delay for the user.

Comment: Thanks. And my action is to write to the DB to match the change the component has already made in the UI so no `StateHasChanged()` call needed.